# Send in-memory bytes (file) over multipart/form-data POST request. Python

Tags: python, sockets, python-requests, byte, multipartform-data

---

**;TLDR**

I want to send a file with requests.send() using `multipart/form-data` request without storing the file on a hard drive. Basically, I'm looking for an alternative for `open()` function for `bytes` object

---

Hello, I'm currently trying to send `multipart/form-data` request and pass in-memory files in it, but I can't figure out how to do that.

My app receives images from one source and sends them to another. Currently it sends get request directly to file, (e.g. `requests.get('https://service.com/test.jpeg')`), reads image's bytes and writes them into new file on the hard drive. The sending code that works looks like this:

```
def send_file(path_to_image: str)
    url = get_upload_link()
    data = {'photo': open(path_to_image, 'rb')}
    r = requests.post(url, files=data)

send_file("test.jpeg")
```

---

The main issue I have with this approach is that I have to keep files on my hard drive. Sure, I can use my drive as some sort of a "temporary buffer" and just delete them after I no longer need these files, but I believe there's much more simple way to do that.

I want my function to receive `bytes` object and then send it. I actually tried doing that, but the backend doesn't accept them. Here's what I tried to do

**Attempt 1**

```
def send_file(image: bytes)
    url = get_upload_link()
    data = {'photo': open(image, 'rb')}
    r = requests.post(url, files=data)
```

I get `"ValueError: embedded null byte"`

**Attempt 2**

```
def upload_photo(image: bytes):
    url = get_upload_link()
    file = BytesIO(image)
    data = {'photo': file}

    r = requests.post(url, files=data)
```

Backend server doesn't process my files correctly. It's like passing `files=None`, same response

---

I also tried:

1. sending the returning value of the methods: `file.getbuffer()` and `file.read()`
2. `file.write(image)` and then sending file
3. `StringsIO` object

etc.

---

**Final notes**

I noticed, that `open()` returns `_io.BufferedReader` object. I also looked for a way to construct its instance, but couldn't fund a way. Can someone help me, please?

UPD:
If anyone is interested, [the receiving api is this](https://dev.vk.com/api/upload#%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the official documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file):

> POST a Multipart-Encoded File
> ...
> If you want, **you can send strings to
> be received as files**:
>
> ```
> url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
> files = {'file': ('report.csv', 'some,data,to,send\nanother,row,to,send\n')}
>
> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
> ```

Comment: Thank you!! I solved it using this: `data = {'photo': ('test.png', image)}`, where image is `bytes` object

Answer (score -1):

I was just grappling with this. I'm transferring a PDF document from an Azure blob storage to another system requests. In this case the API required sending a request body in JSON and the file in a multipart/form-data POST request.

I found that BytesIO was not necessary, contrary to expectations.

```
blobclient = tx.blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=blobcontainer, blob=blobname)
blobdata = blobclient.download_blob()

blobjson = json.loads(blobdata.readall().decode("utf-8"))

blobbytes = b64decode(blobjson['contentBytes']) # I was wrapping this in BytesIO() but it didn't work so I removed it. 

filetuple = [
      ("request", ("request", json.dumps(doc_body).encode("utf-8"), "application/json")),
      ("file", (filename, blobbytes, blobjson['contentType']))
            ]

requests.post(url=url, files=files, headers = headers) # In this case the API uses HMAC authentication so headers were necessary, but in other cases they can be removed, as requests will create its own
```